# Can someone describe to me what RSpec 2 is doing in this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I have been attempting to dive into RSpec 2 but its auto generated controller specs do not work for any version of RSpec 2 with any version of Ruby or any version of Rails. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

```
def mock_category(stubs={})
  @mock_category ||= mock_model(Category, stubs).as_null_object
end

describe "GET show" do
  it "assigns the requested category as @category" do
    Category.stub(:find).with("37") { mock_category }
    get :show, :id => "37"
    assigns(:category).should be(mock_category)
  end
end
```

This is auto generated from `rails g scaffold Category`

RSpec returns this :

```
Failures:
   1) CategoriesController GET show assigns the requested category as @category
    Failure/Error: assigns(:category).should be(mock_category)
    expected Category_1002, got nil
    # ./spec/controllers/categories_controller_spec.rb:21
    # /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `inject'
```

Why is this mock/stub returning `nil` ?

**Update**

This is from my controller's show method :

```
def show
   @category = Category.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @category }
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what `.as_null_object` does or why it's there, but that seems like it shouldn't be there. Try removing it.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the index method?

Comment: @zetetic, I'm an idiot, I posted the wrong example. The one above is only slightly different. Is there any method you would like to see from it?

Comment: @rspeicher, Not entirely sure what it does either, but it makes no different whether its there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSpec has some serious conflicts between Rails3 beta, and RSpec 2 beta.10 to Rails3 release, and RSpec 2 beta.20.

I tried copying and pasting the differences between the scaffolds, but I cleared up the sitation entirely by deleting all the specs, and regenerating them. Uninstalling `haml`, and installing only `haml-rails` for rails 3.

All the specs run now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Well if something's wrong, I sure don't see it. Maybe the `show` action isn't being reached at all? Are there any `before_filter` statements getting in the way?

You could try adding some tests to see if the assignment is being reached. Like

`controller.should_receive(:show)`

btw `.as_null_object` tells the mock to ignore messages that you don't stub. This helps with objects that depend on validations or other constraints, which you would otherwise have to stub out in order to get an object that you can test. But be careful not to ignore messages that you should be testing for.

Comment: I think I've deduced this down to that its missing some fundamental part of the generator. Because I can't recreate the problem , I find that because the project was started with Rails 3 beta, and the new Rspec, that the generators conflict. And I'm not sure how to strip rspec from the project and regenreate them.

Comment: You've heard the saying, "never trust a junkie"? To that I add: "never trust a generator" :)