# How to completely remove Rspec and its generated files, and reinstall them into a project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

Is it possible to completely remove rspec from a project, and then reinstall it again?

The reason I ask is because I had started my project on Rails 3 beta, and now that the new one has come out, the new rspec conflicts and nothing passes. But if I start a new project, everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: There should be no need for something that drastic. I have maintained a project from rails3.0.0.beta4 through to 3.0.0, upgrading each time a new rails or rspec2 version came out. I have had a few hiccups, but all were easily fixed. Most were related to view-testing, in my case. If you list some errors, i am sure i could say something more relevant.

Comment: Sure check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637824/can-someone-describe-to-me-what-rspec-2-is-doing-in-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its not rspec that needs to be removed like Nathanvda recommended in his comment,  but HAML does need to be removed in Rails 3. Instead I used the haml-rails gem, and uninstalled all older version of haml. Works like a gem now. :D

Then what I did was deleted all the specs that were created for my other scaffolds, and regenerated them.